# Почему не работает CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

У меня есть CollectionView с кнопками которые будут отображать время (Кликабельные).

Вот мой код:

```
import UIKit

class CreateWindow: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
    var items = ["11:30","12:30","13:30","14:30","15:30","16:30"]

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
}

extension CreateWindow: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol
    
    // tell the collection view how many cells to make
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(self.items.count)
        return self.items.count
    }
    
    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print(self.items.count)
        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TimeCollection
        
        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell.TimeLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // make cell more visible in our example project
        
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }
}

class TimeCollection: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var TimeLabel: UILabel!
    
}
```

Вот мой storyboard:
[image: Storyboard]

`collectionView.delegate` я пробовал и через код swift и через сам storyboard привязывал к `ViewController`.
При запуске срабатывает только функция кол-во ячеек, а функция их создания - нет (`print` ничего не выводит)
Кто нибудь знает как решить эту проблему?

---

Дополнительная информация:

Скриншот моих слоев (Collection не заполнена)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объявление класса у Cell
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зависимости CollectionView
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зависимости Cell

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас не указан в сториборд Custom Class для ячейки - нужно дать понять collection view какой класс для ячейки использовать. После этого соедините `@IBOutlet weak var TimeLabel: UILabel!` с лейблом в ячейке в сториборд и все должно заработать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнение**

вот так нужно сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнение 2**

вот так выглядит в Debug View Hierarchy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнение 3**

посмотрите исходники сториборд (Open As - Source Code), есть ли там ваш класс ячейки `customClass="TimeCollection"`. Иногда для его установки еще приходится нажимать Enter в поле ввода Custom Class

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дополнение 4**

В целом, если не заработает, можно попробовать вынести ячейку в отдельный xib (да и вообще так лучше), тогда ее нужно будет зарегистрировать, в остальном все так же (я назвал класс `TimeCollectionViewCell`)

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self
self.collectionView.dataSource = self
self.collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "TimeCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Comment: Добрый день, в этом и беда, я это сделал... Я делал все четко по этому примеру https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735228/how-to-make-a-simple-collection-view-with-swift
TimeCollection у меня привязан к ячейке и идентификатор cell я ей тоже задал.

Comment: @Kirzzz см дополнение, вы так сделали?

Comment: @schimdt9, Да. У меня как будто не вызывается метод создания ячеек, потому что принты в нем не выводятся. Я думал это из-за FSCalendar который у меня подключен к этому окну ( ведь он тоже по принципу CellCollection вроде ), но после того, как отключил - все равно ничего не появляется. После запуска приложения когда смотрю слой CellCollection - он пуст ( это к тому что не из-за заданной высоты ничего не показывается )

Comment: @Kirzzz попробуйте создать чистый проект с нуля и посмотрите, у меня все сразу заработало - я взял ваш код, установил Identifier и класс для ячейки, протянул аутлет для лейбла и все

Comment: @Kirzzz еще дополнил ответ

Comment: попробовал новый ViewController в том же storyboard, и там все конечно заработало. Но когда тоже самое 1 в 1 делаю в нужном окне - ничего не получается, пробовал пересоздавать, но в итоге - ничего

Comment: @Kirzzz пробовали очистку DerivedData, Clean - Build?

Comment: @Kirzzz  см Дополнение 3

Comment: @Kirzzz см Дополнение 4

Comment: @Kirzzz и в чем была причина?

Comment: огромное вам спасибо за вашу помощь! Помогло полное пересоздание блока с удалением старых классов, видимо в истории где-то действительно я ошибался при создании из-за чего он не распознавал правильный вариант

Comment: @Kirzzz да такое бывает, что остаются старые ссылки после переделок

Comment: как жаль что Xcode - не создание сайтов через JS+CSS+HTML+PHP)))

Comment: @Kirzzz да здесь своя атмосфера